# cant read data of struct vector

Tags: c++, fstream

I am writing these codes to read data from file then write then into various vectors defined inside a struct. Can you please tell me why can I not access them using another function (write_table in this case). Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void read_data (string file_name);
void write_table ();

struct Record {
    vector <string> myv;
    vector <string> bwv;
};

int main ()
{
    read_data("data.txt");
    Record o;

    write_table (o);

}

void read_data (string file_name)
{
    Record r;

    ifstream data_in (file_name.c_str());
    static ofstream data_out ("tuna.txt");
    if (!data_in)
    {
        cout<<"Failed to open file"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        string dummyline;
        getline (data_in, dummyline);
        string  my, bw;
        while (data_in>>my>>bw)
        {
            {
            r.myv.push_back(my);
            r.bwv.push_back(bw);
            }
        }
        data_in.close();
    }
    data_out<<"MY"<<'\t'<<"BW"<<endl;
    size_t size=r.myv.size();
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<r.myv[i]<<'\t'<<r.bwv[i]<<endl;
        //data_out<<r.myv[i]<<'\t'<<r.bwv[i]<<endl;
    }


}


void write_table (Record bo)
{

   size_t size = bo.myv.size();
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<bo.myv[i]<<'\t'<<bo.bwv[i]<<endl;

    }

}
```

---

I reorganised my program as suggestion of Songyuanya as follows> My clear question (as suggestion of James) is: I want to write another function write_table inside class Record, to print out the two vectors: myv and bwv to screen/ or write them to file later. Thanks

//Main cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Record.h"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    Record r;
    r.read_data("data.txt");

}
```

Record.h

```
#ifndef RECORD_H
#define RECORD_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Record
{
    public:
        Record();
        void read_data (string file_name);

    private:
    vector <string> myv;
    vector <string> bwv;
};

#endif // RECORD_H
```

Record.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Record.h"
using namespace std;


Record::Record()
{
    //ctor
}
void Record::read_data (string file_name)
{
    ifstream data_in (file_name.c_str());
    static ofstream data_out ("tuna.txt");
    if (!data_in)
    {
        cout<<"Failed to open file"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        string dummyline;
        getline (data_in, dummyline);
        string  my, bw;
        while (data_in>>my>>bw)
        {
                {
                myv.push_back(my);
                bwv.push_back(bw);
                }
        }
        data_in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You forward declare a function with no arguments, and then pass it arguments in `main`. I don't know what you mean by "why can't I access them" because you can, if you want to.

Comment: I edited the function prototype as :void write_table (Record bo); but it still does not work

Comment: Create a [mcve] with emphasis on a clear problem statement and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the object of `Record` across `read_data` and `write_table` by parameter or return value.

If it's shared and processed by `read_data` and `write_table`, why not make `read_data` and `write_table` member functions and encapsulate them into one class?

```
class Record {
private:
    vector <string> myv;
    vector <string> bwv;
public:
    void read_data (string file_name);
    void write_table ();
};

void Record::read_data (string file_name) {
    // using myv and bwv...
}

void Record::write_table () {
    // using myv and bwv...
   size_t size = myv.size();
   for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
       cout<<myv[i]<<'\t'<<bwv[i]<<endl;
   }
}

int main ()
{
    Record o;
    o.read_data("data.txt");
    o.write_table();
}
```

Comment: I have already wrapped all such data function into one class. However, still cannot get to the point of write_table function.

Comment: @hieu What do you mean "cannot get to the point of write_table function"? Still can't access the vectors?

Comment: @hieu Can't get what you mean. I've edited my answer, try to write `write_table()`, is it fine?

Comment: it worked, thanks so much! And the codes look more organised when being wrapped inside a class. Thanks again.

Comment: @hieu Glad can help. :D